# How to find the formula to this summation and the prove it by induction?

Tags: number-theory, induction, combinations

I need to find the formula of the sum below and the prove it by induction. Sadly so far I have not been able to succed. My problem is finding the formula.

The formula: $$\sum_{k = 0}^n (2k + 1)*C_n^k = ? $$

What I have done so far: $$\sum_{k = 0}^n C_n^k * x^k = (x + 1)^n $$
For $ x = 1: $  $$\sum_{k = 0}^n C_n^k = 2^n$$

Then I multiplied both sides by $$\sum_{k = 0}^n (2k + 1) $$ 
And then I get that: $$\sum_{k = 0}^n (2k + 1) * C_n^k = 2^n * (n + 1)^2 $$

But sadly I messed up somewhere because for $n = 1$ this is not true..
Maybe I am not allowed to multiply with a summation like that.
Please help me find the formula and explain what I did wrong!

Edit 1: $ C_n^k  $ =  binomial coefficient. I learned to write it this way.
Edit 2: Thank your for the help!

Comment: The last step is incorrect since the product of the sums need not be the sum of the products.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik $C^k_n$ is another way of writing the binomial coefficient $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{n} (2k + 1) \binom{n}{k}
= 2 \sum_{k = 0}^{n} k \binom{n}{k} + \sum_{k = 0}^{n}  \binom{n}{k}
= 2 \underbrace{\sum_{k = 0}^{n} k \binom{n}{k}}_{:= S} + 2^n
$$
Since [$(x + 1)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} x^k$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) we have
$$
n (x + 1)^{n - 1}
= \frac{d}{dx} (x + 1)^n
= \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{d}{dx} x^k
= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} k x^{k-1}
$$
With $x = 1$ you find $S = n 2^{n - 1}$ and therefore
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{n} (2k + 1) \binom{n}{k}
= 2n 2^{n - 1} + 2^n
= n 2^n + 2^n
= 2^n (n + 1).
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Apply $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}$ to $(x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^nC^k_nx^k$. (However, this will lead to a direct proof, not a proof by induction)